# How to call C# code triggered by some JavaScript event with the help of Selenium webdriver?

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I've Googled about this problem but could not find any questions about this (the inverse direction - execute JavaScript code - is of course more common).

If I remember correctly, there is some support to do this by using some .NET WebBrowser or WebView control.

Please note that triggering the code from some JavaScript event means the source of action flow is not from C# code as the following does:

```
var someResult = driver.ExecuteAsyncScript("var cb=arguments[0]; cb(someJsVariable);");
```

Here you can clearly see that the callback `cb` is executed inside JavaScript environment and looks really like that it flows and continues to run in the C# environment. However it's obvious the source of the entire flow is started from inside C# code (by the call `driver.ExecuteAsyncScript`).

My scenario is completely different. I want some kind of JavaScript code executing by any event inside JavaScript environment (e.g: document.onload, button.onclick, ...) and actually here I want to intercept the `ajaxSend` (of course this can be triggered by any action started inside the JavaScript environment) to send back the request options to C# environment.

So there should be some C# callback for the JavaScript code to call, something like this:

```
driver.ExecuteScript("$(document).ajaxSend(function(e,jXhr,options){ /* somehow trigger C# callback here to send back the options */ });");
```

If this cannot be done, I think Selenium should add this capability in future, it's a shame that a simple WebBrowser control can do this whereas a powerful WebDriver cannot.